# Jquery datatable and editable change value inline without pressing enter

Tags: jquery, datatables, jeditable

I am using jquery jeditable and datatable in my project where I have created an editable table.When I click on a cell,it will allow me to edit it.
Below is my code

```
var theCallback = function(v, s) {       
    return v;
};
$(otable).editable(theCallback, {
    "callback": function(sValue, y) {
        var apos = otable.fnGetPosition(this);
        otable.fnUpdate(sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1]);           
    },   
});
```

The problem with this is ,I need to press enter after changing the value for value to be reflected in table.It wont change if I just move out of focus from cell but I want to implement that.
How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an option in jeditable. I believe all you need is to add the property `onblur: 'submit'`, as mentioned in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402227/jquery-jeditable-without-ok-and-cancel-buttons).